# Xamarin change page from a renderer Button

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a renderer button in iOS and what I am trying to do is to trigger another page  into the stack when it gets a swipe gesture.

if I implement that on my MainPage, for the Clicked it is quiete straight forward. as I can use "this"

```
    public class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage ()
        {
            // Button bottom 1
            var button = new Button { 
                Text = "button",
                HeightRequest = 60,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,

            };
            button.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
                await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new nextPage());
            };
       }
}
```

but How could I do this in a rendered button in iOS.

my renderer button is like this:

```
public class MYButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeGestureRecognizerUp;

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            swipeGestureRecognizerUp = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer (() => onSwipeUp());
            swipeGestureRecognizerUp.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up;

            if (e.NewElement == null) 
            {

                if (swipeGestureRecognizerUp != null) 
                {
                    this.RemoveGestureRecognizer (swipeGestureRecognizerUp);
                }
            }

            if (e.OldElement == null) 
            {
                this.AddGestureRecognizer (swipeGestureRecognizerUp);
            }
        }

        private void onSwipeUp()
        {
           //here it's where I would like to change the page to a new one.
        }
    }
```

is this possible??
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice way to do this would be to combine your custom renderer with a custom button view. Your custom view could have a swipe event to which you can subscribe. Of course, you could create a custom delegate if necessary as well, to pass custom event data, but I've kept this example simple.

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public event EventHandler OnSwipeUp;

    public void FireSwipeUp()
    {
        var swipeUp = OnSwipeUp;
        if (swipeUp != null)
            swipeUp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

From your custom renderer, you can fire the custom event by calling the `FireSwipeUp` method.

```
private void onSwipeUp()
{
    ((CustomButton)Element).FireSwipeUp();
}
```

Now you can subscribe to your custom `OnSwipeUp` event from within your `MainPage` class, just as you do with `Clicked`.

```
// Button bottom 1
var button = new CustomButton { 
    Text = "button",
    HeightRequest = 60,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
};

button.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
     await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new nextPage());
};

button.OnSwipeUp += async (sender, e) => {
     await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new nextPage());
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand how I can have a button of Type CustomButton in my shared project if I have my CustomButton(button view) and my buttonRenderer in my iOsProject. Am I missing something?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. I'm not at my mac so I can't test it, but I've edited my answer. The button now inherits from Button instead, which is the shared Xamarin.Forms button type. You can put this in your shared project. I've changed the code in the iOS renderer to use renderer's Model property to access the shared Xamarin.Forms control. Let me know if it works. :)

Comment: Now it is complaining in the "((CustomButton)Model).FireSwipeUp();" it says that "Model" doesn't exist in this context. I've got it works in another ugly way. But I would like to do it in the way that you propose, it is much more clever than my.

Comment: I've just updated to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms, and now I'm getting the same error. The APIs have been a little fluid while Xamarin have been finalising Forms. It may now be called Element instead of Model.